# Http session is being destroyed without the user being logged off

Tags: java, session, garbage-collection

From time to time, we get this in our logs:

```
2016-09-14 10:43:04,183 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  HttpSessionListener - User Username logged out
```

This line comes from the following code in our custom HttpSessionListener:

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed(javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent)
     */
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {

        HttpSession session = httpSessionEvent.getSession();
        UserContainer userContainer = (UserContainer) session.getAttribute(UserContainer.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE);
        if(userContainer != null) {
            LoginView loginView = userContainer.getLoginView();
            // A REST client may do a failed login after witch it has a session and a UserContainer with a null loginView. 
            if (loginView != null) {
                String userId = loginView.getUserId();
                String userName = loginView.getUserName();
                // remove the user container from the UserContainerManager
                UserContainerManager.getInstance().removeUserContainer(userContainer);
                // log logout event
                LOGGER.info(String.format("User %s - %s logged out", userId, userName));
            } else {
                // remove the user container from the UserContainerManager
                UserContainerManager.getInstance().removeUserContainer(userContainer);
                // Failed login already logged by the LoginService.
            }

        }
    }
```

Some background information on our Session management: we have a UserContainer class in our session so we can keep all user-related information in one object. This object also contains a transient reference to the session.

```
public class UserContainer implements HttpSessionBindingListener, HttpSessionActivationListener,
        Serializable {

    // HttpSession associated with this UserContainer :
    private transient HttpSession httpSession;

    /**
     * The container calls this method when it is being bound to the session.
     *
     * @param event the event that identifies the session
     */
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        httpSession = event.getSession();
    }

    /**
     * Notifies the object that it is being unbound from a session. Used here
     * to remove the userid from the list of the logged in users when a
     * session has expired.
     *
     * @param e the event that identifies the session
     */
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent e) {
    }

    /**
     * Invalidate the httpSession of this user.
     */
    public void invalidateHttpSession() {
        httpSession.invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @return the httpSession for this user.
     */
    public HttpSession getHttpSession() {
        return httpSession;
    }
}
```

When we get the above line, the user that's referred to stays connected, but most actions fail for them and they have to login again. Their UserContainer object is destroyed, but their session remains.

I personally think that this is because the httpSession object in their UserContainer is getting GC'd, triggering sessionDestroyed event and destroying their UserContainer. My coworker, however, says that, since Java is a ByRef language, the httpSession object in the UserContainer being GC'd should also GC the httpSession that the UserContainer is in, which doesn't happen because the user doesn't get thrown back to the login screen on their next request.

What could cause this?

Comment: No. An object in a session can't be GC'd until the session is GC'd, and the session hasn't been GC'd yet because is still reachable via the `HttpSessionEvent,`so there goes your hypothesis. Your colleague isn't any more correct than you are: the GC of one object doesn't entail GC of another, however they may be related. My guess is that the session is being timed out, and that your data structures don't work correctly in that case.

Comment: yes @EJP is correct. You must check the timeout period of your web server. User session is invalidated after configured timeout if there is no activity for that session.

Comment: @EJP The weird thing is that, if it was related to just the session timing out, the timings don't match. My Tomcat web.xml has session-timeout set to 30 (which i assume means 30 minutes). However, I'm having logouts after 34 minutes, after 20 minutes, after 14 minutes (with last activity being about 8 minutes ago). If this was related to the Tomcat session timeout settings, it shouldn't be that inconsistent, I think.

Comment: @Nzall The Tomcat `session-timeout` is in minutes and relates to time since last activity. The other times you mention are irrelevant. The 8 minute one clearly isn't a timeout, it was induced by your application somehow, but again somehow your use of these session variables doesn't marry up.